# Reformatting a dict where the values have a dict-like relationship

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a defaultdict that looks like this:

```
d = { 'ID_001': ['A', 'A_part1', 'A_part2'], 
      'ID_002': ['A', 'A_part3'],
      'ID_003': ['B', 'B_part1', 'B_part2', 'A', 'A_part4'],
      'ID_004': ['C', 'C_part1', 'A', 'A_part5', 'B', 'B_part3']
    }
```

Before I go any further, I have to say that `A_part1` isn't the actual string -- the strings are really a bunch of alphanumeric characters; I represented it as such to show that `A_part1` is text that is associated with `A`, if you see what I mean.)

Standing back and looking at it, what I really have is a dict where the values have their own key/value relationship, but that relationship exists only in the order they appear in, in the list.

I am attempting to end up with something like this:

```
['ID_001 A A_part1, A_part2',
 'ID_002 A A_part3',
 'ID_003 B B_part1 B_part2',
 'ID_003 A A_part4',
 'ID_004 C C_part1',
 'ID_004 A A_part5',
 'ID_004 B B_part3']
```

I have made a variety of attempts; I keep wanting to run through the dict's value, making note of the character in the first position (eg, the `A`), and collect values until I find a `B` or a `C`, then stop collecting. Then append what I have to a list that I have declared elsewhere. Ad nauseum.

I'm running into all sorts of problems, not the least of which is bloated code. I'm missing the ability to iterate through the value in a clean way. Invariably, I seem to run into index errors.

If anyone has any ideas/philosophy/comments I'd be grateful.

Comment: Why `ID_001` and `A_part3` are skipped?

Comment: arg I gotta edit that typo!! thanks

Comment: Could you explain how your dictionary maps into the array?

Comment: @VedaadShakib it is just a key/value relationship; the key references the value, which is a list. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
d = { 'ID_001': ['A', 'A_part1', 'A_part2'],
      'ID_002': ['A', 'A_part3'],
      'ID_003': ['B', 'B_part1', 'B_part2', 'A', 'A_part4'],
      'ID_004': ['C', 'C_part1', 'A', 'A_part5', 'B', 'B_part3']
    }

def is_key(s):
    return s in ['A','B','C']

out = {}
for (k,v) in d.iteritems():
    key = None
    for e in v:
        if is_key(e): key = e
        else:
            out_key = (k,key)
            out[out_key] = out.get(out_key, []) + [e]
```

which generates:

```
{('ID_001', 'A'): ['A_part1', 'A_part2'],
 ('ID_002', 'A'): ['A_part3'],
 ('ID_003', 'A'): ['A_part4'],
 ('ID_003', 'B'): ['B_part1', 'B_part2'],
 ('ID_004', 'A'): ['A_part5'],
 ('ID_004', 'B'): ['B_part3'],
 ('ID_004', 'C'): ['C_part1']}
```

It's important that you update the `is_key` function to match your actual input.

Also, the variable names are far from optimal, but I'm not really sure what you're doing -- you should be able to (and should) give them more appropriate names.

Answer (score 0):

May not be in the order you want, but no thanks for further headaches.

```
d = { 'ID_001': ['A', 'A_part1', 'A_part2'], 
      'ID_002': ['A', 'A_part3'],
      'ID_003': ['B', 'B_part1', 'B_part2', 'A', 'A_part4'],
      'ID_004': ['C', 'C_part1', 'A', 'A_part5', 'B', 'B_part3']
    }
rst = []
for o in d:
    t_d={}

    for t_o in d[o]:
        if not t_o[0] in t_d:
            t_d[t_o[0]] = [t_o]
        else: t_d[t_o[0]].append(t_o)
    for t_o in t_d:
        rst.append(' '.join([o,t_d[t_o][0],', '.join(t_d[t_o][1:])]))
print(rst)
```

https://ideone.com/FeBDLA

```
['ID_004 C C_part1', 'ID_004 A A_part5', 'ID_004 B B_part3', 'ID_003 A A_part4', 'ID_003 B B_part1, B_part2', 'ID_002 A A_part3', 'ID_001 A A_part1, A_part2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're trying to do something involving contiguous groups, you should think of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html). You weren't very specific about what condition separates the groups, but if we take "the character in the first position" at face value:

```
from itertools import groupby

new_list = []
for key, sublist in sorted(d.items()):
    for _, group in groupby(sublist, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        new_list.append(' '.join([key] + list(group)))
```

produces

```
>>> for elem in new_list:
...     print(elem)
...     
ID_001 A A_part1 A_part2
ID_002 A A_part3
ID_003 B B_part1 B_part2
ID_003 A A_part4
ID_004 C C_part1
ID_004 A A_part5
ID_004 B B_part3
```

Comment: I can't profess to confidently read this code but I will do my research...super excited to learn itertools but have found it hard to come across much instructive materials on the module. Thanks for your response.